# orthogonal complement in $\ell_{2}$ to subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

How to find orthogonal complement in $\ell_{2}$ to $L = \{x\in\ell_{2},x=(a_{1},a_{2}...):\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} = 0\}$. I just don't know how to approach. I know that this subpace is closed, i.e dense in whole space. I want to find complement without knowing that $L$ is everywhere dense. But i just can't find complement subspace. Any hints?

Comment: I don't think "closed" means the same as "dense in the whole space". In any case, in any Hilbert space $L^\perp = \bar{L}^\perp$, if as you say that $L$ is everywhere dense, then $\bar{L} = H$, and that should tell you what its complement is.

Comment: @WillieWong so answer will be zero space $\{0\}$, i.e complement ? Because $L$ everywhere dense

Comment: I edited, because *orthogonal* has an *r*

Comment: What is $n$ in the summation? Is it a fixed number?

Comment: It's enough to prove that the orthogonal complement is one-dimensional, then the span of the vector $(1,1,...,1,0,0,...)$ (where $n$ units) will be the answer.